# Redirect to thank you page after finishing the survey using jquery

Tags: list

I have a survey list with multiple questions once i fill up and click on finish it should get redirected to thank you page. I want to do it using jquery not with designer.Can any one provide snippet for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use window.location. it's a property that will tell you the current URL location of the browser. Setting the property to something different will redirect the page

window.location.href = 'http://www.just4sharing.com'; //Will take you to just4sharing.

Similarly you can also use:

window.location.search = 'http://www.just4sharing.com';

window.location = 'http://www.just4sharing.com';

Comment: Joseph in brief can you tell how to use window.location. Thanks

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio or You use just SharePoint Designer?

Comment: I am using designer.

Comment: Sorry, I have very little experience with Designer. When you are able to insert Jquery in designer, you can straightly use this command, window.location.href = 'your new page' after the completion of your process.

Comment: i have just given the link of my thankyou page.aspx in the designer for finish button and it worked.

Comment: I haven't tried to do the same in jquery i am bit confused...